# Get WordEditor property in Word Document

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-word, office-interop, office-automation

I need to obtain the **WordEditor** property to Word object in order to work with the word document.

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using System.Reflection;
using WORD = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Outlook.Application outlookapp = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = outlookapp.GetNamespace("MAPI");

            nameSpace.Logon("", "", Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

            Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookapp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

            Outlook.Inspector inspector = mail.GetInspector;

           inspector.Activate();

          // here I get error.
            WORD.Document word = inspector.WordEditor;
           
        }
    }
}
```

why I'm getting error when trying to get the wordeditor to a word document ?, Also need revised code for the above

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko  I get erro on on this line : `WORD.Document word = inspector.WordEditor;`    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The operation failed.

Comment: Does it work if you call `mail.Display(false)` before accessing the inspector?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Also not working.

Comment: Does it matter if Outlook is running at the time your code is executed?

Comment: No, code is executed normally till I get error in line of `inspector.WordEditor;`. error as follows **System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The operation failed.'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have installed the recent updates to my Outlook and the issue got solved.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use the Word object model in your code you need to add a COM reference. To add a reference to a primary interop assembly:

1. Open your Office project and select the project name in `Solution Explorer`.
2. On the `Project` menu, click `Add Reference`.
3. On the .NET tab, select the primary interop assembly you want in the `Component Name` list. For more information about the available Microsoft Office primary interop assemblies, see [Office primary interop assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).
4. Click OK.

The assembly name appears in the `References` folder of `Solution Explorer`.

You can read more about the Word editor in Outlook in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/dd492012(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: Please note that I do the same through console applciation. so can you please advise the name of the reference that I should add.

Comment: The guide makes sense for all kind of applications where you try to automate Word.

Comment: Im trying but stuck at this line.WORD.Document document =inspector.WordEditor;

Comment: can you please help me I have ameneded the code.

Comment: The `WordEditor` property is only valid if the `IsWordMail` method returns `True` and the `EditorType` property is `olEditorWord`. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, they both returned true. I tested them

Comment: Try to display the inspector window and then get the word editor to make sure it was initialized correctly.

Comment: Not working also. and I'm getting the inspector window dispalyed.

Comment: Do you have Word installed on the system? Have you tried repairing MS Office?